# How can I efficiently compute $\binom{N}{N/2} \mod P^2 $

Tags: number-theory, modular-arithmetic

I am looking to compute $\binom{N}{N/2}\mod P^2 $ in lesser than $O(P^2)$ as well as lesser than $O(N)$
where $P<N<P^2$

It is important to note the range of $N$, if $N<P$ then even multiplying all terms explicitly and taking modulo is essentially $O(P)$

The algorithm [here](https://cp-algorithms.com/algebra/factorial-modulo.html#algorithm) can help us compute $\binom{N}{R}\mod P$ in $O(P)$,
If we apply the same(or almost similar) algorithm for $\binom{N}{R} \mod P^2$, then it becomes $O(P^2)$.

However there are libraries like [FLINT](https://fredrikj.net/blog/2012/03/factorials-mod-n-and-wilsons-theorem/) which computes $N! \mod M$ in $O(N^{1/2}\log^3{N})$ (which I don't fully understand yet), My guess is we would have to do something similar to compute $N! \mod P^2$ in ~$O(P)$.

.....

I will jot down whatever I understand of FLINT with an example(will convert it to an answer once I have the full understanding),

Let's say we are computing 50! mod 7

- Step 1: We need to compute polynomial,
  P(x)=(x+1)(x+2)(x+3)(x+4)(x+5)(x+6)(x+7)
- Step 2: Evaluate P(0),P(7),P(14),P(21),P(28),P(35),P(42),P(49)
- Step 3: Product P(0)P(7)P(14)P(21)P(28)P(35)P(42)P(49) gives !50

Step1 can be done using FFT based multiplication multiple times ie,
$2\log2.P/2+4\log4.P/4+8\log8.P/8+...+2^{log P}\log2^{logP}.1=Plog2+Plog4+Plog8+...+Plog{P}=P\log2^{\sum{log{P}}}=O(P\log^2{P})$

Step2 can be done in,
$O(P\log^2{P})$ using [Multi Point Evaluation](https://cp-algorithms.com/algebra/polynomial.html#multi-point-evaluation) algorithm and

Step3 is $O(P)$.

Total=$O(P\log^2{P}+P\log^2{P}+P)=O(P\log^2{P})$

I am probably missing something as Fredrik Johansson
mentions it as $O(P\log^3{P})$

.....

Coming back to our problem and our example that I gave @aryaman-maithani ie $140!\mod 49$, ie $P=7$.For $1 \to 98$ there is no issue as it can be computed in $O(P)$ by the technique @aryaman-maithani suggested.

Issue is with $99.100.101....139.140$ part

Lets explore similar trick as above.
In polynomial P(x)=(x+1)(x+2)(x+3)(x+4)(x+5)(x+6)(x+7)
for our case we need to evaluate P(98)P(105)P(112)P(119)P(126)P(133)

even after that we would be left with the point 140 which we can multiply explicitly. Note explicit multiplication can be at the most 6 ie $O(P)$ as opposed to $O(P^2)$ which @aryaman-maithani was suggesting.

But one thing I didn't mention till now, the above polynomial is wrong for us as we need to strip off $7$ from $98,105, 112, 119, 126, 133$ right?
Or better if we drop the last term $(x+7)$ and compute for $98,105, 112, 119, 126, 133$ later in the recursive way that we did for earlier multiples of P as suggested by @aryaman-maithani . So correct polynomial for our case is $P(x)=(x+1)(x+2)(x+3)(x+4)(x+5)(x+6)$

.....

I should add, if someone is just looking to compute factorial(without bothering about inverting) all the above steps are overkill. Stripping $P$ is for people who needs to invert. Additionally you need not calculate complexity in terms of $P$ either. Because $N$ can not be significantly larger than $P$ with a non zero  $N! mod P^2$ but for  $\binom{n}{r}$ 's case $N$ can be lot larger than $P$ or even larger than $P^2$ and yet have a non-zero $N! mod P^2$ result.
Which is why you would have noticed Fredrik Johansson express complexity in terms of N because in $N! mod P$ answer will be zero for $N \ge P$ similarly in $N! mod P^2$ answer will be zero for $N \ge 2P$

Comment: I'd love to know how this came up in practice :-)

Comment: @AdamZalcman: Based on the numbers, I'd guess that [this Project Euler question](https://projecteuler.net/problem=824) is the source (released yesterday).

Comment: From your link : "Generalizations of Lucas's theorem to the case of p being a prime power are given by Davis and Webb (1990)[3] and Granville (1997).[4]"

Comment: @DanielV What is the time complexity of Davis and Webb's algorithm ?

Answer (score 2):

Assuming you did mean $\mod p^2$, where $p = 10^{\color{red}{7}} + 19$, one can verify that $p$ divides the binomial coefficient of your choice. (This is done easily on a computer since you can explicitly compute the highest power of $p$ dividing $n!$ quickly. Or you may use Lucas' theorem that you cite.)

Thus, you can use the following generalisation of Lucas' theorem:

> If $0 \leqslant B \leqslant A$ are integers and $p$ a prime, write $A$, $B$, and $A - B$ in $p$-adic notation as
> \begin{align} 
> A &= a_r p^r + \cdots + a_1 p + a_0, \\
> B &= b_r p^r + \cdots + b_1 p + b_0, \\ 
> A - B &= c_r p^r + \cdots + c_1 p + c_0.
> \end{align}
> (Here, $a_r \neq 0$.)  If $p^t$ divides $\binom{A}{B}$, then
> $$\binom{A}{B} \equiv (-p^t) \prod_{i = 0}^{r} \frac{a_i!}{b_i! c_i!} \pmod{p^{t + 1}}.$$

Source: The first page of [Kenneth S. Davis, William A. Webb (1990). "Lucas' Theorem for Prime Powers". European Journal of Combinatorics. 11 (3): 229–233.](https://doi.org/10.1016%2FS0195-6698%2813%2980122-9).

The paper, in turn, cites "G. S. Kazandzidis, Congruences on binomial coefficients, Bull. Soc. Math. Grece (NS), 9 (1968), 1-12" for the above.

---

It may be a cause of concern as to how one can compute $$\frac{a!}{b! c!} \pmod{p^t}$$ when $a$, $b$, $c$ are large.

Here's a sketch: Call that binomial coefficient $B$.

First, note that you can compute the largest power of $p$ dividing $B$. Call this $n$.
Now, it suffices to compute $(a!)'$, where $(a!)'$ denotes $a!$ after stripping all factors of $p$. (Similarly for $b$ and $c$.)

Note that we can write

$$a! = \prod_{p \nmid k} k \cdot \prod_{p \mid k} k,$$
where $k \leqslant a$ in both products.
The first product can be calculated $\mod p^2$ using group theory (look up queries on calculating the product of all elements in an abelian group).
Since we are interested in calculating $(a!)'$, we must remove a factor of $p$ from all the elements in the second product. But this may still leave some factors of $p$ for those $k$ that were divisible by a higher power of $p$.
In essence, you must do this recursively.

Thus, you have calculated $(a!)'$, $(b!)'$, $(c!)'$ modulo $p^2$. Since these are coprime to $p$, all of these are invertible. Hence, you can invert $(b!)' (c!)'$ modulo $p^t$. (Python has an in-built implementation of this now.)

Finally, multiply with $p^n$ to get your answer (in our case, $n = 1$ can be checked).

---

This sort of idea has been discussed before on this website when trying to compute the last few digits before the trailing zeroes in $a!$. The idea then was to compute $(a!)'$ modulo some prime power. (Again, it was likely inspired from [a Project Euler question](https://projecteuler.net/problem=160).)

---

**Edit.** I'll focus on $t = 2$ here.
For $p$ large, there is an issue with the "residual" calculations. More concretely, given $1 \leqslant n \leqslant p^2$, we want to compute
$$F = \prod_{\substack{i \leq n \\ p \nmid k}} k.$$

Consider the polynomial $f(x) = (x + 1) \cdots (x + (p - 1)) \in \Bbb Z/p^2 [x]$. Modulo $p^2$, we have the identity
$$f(x + kp) = f(x) + kp f'(x).$$
(I suppose this is a Taylor expansion of sorts? But you can prove this by noting that if $R$ is a ring and $\varepsilon \in R$ satisfies $\varepsilon^2 = 0$, then $$(a_1 + \varepsilon) \cdots (a_k + \varepsilon) = a_1 \cdots a_k + \varepsilon \sum_{i = 1}^{k} a_{1} \cdots \widehat{a_{i}} \cdots a_{k}.$$ The sum on the right is going through all possible $k - 1$ products.)

Now, write $n = ap + b$, with $0 \leqslant a < p$ and $1 \leqslant b < p$. (Wlog, we may assume $p \nmid n$.)

Thus, we have
$$F = f(1) f(p + 1) \cdots f((a - 1) p + 1) (ap + 1) \cdots (ap + b).$$
By our earlier identity, we can write this as
$$F = \prod_{k = 0}^{a - 1}(f(1) + kp f'(1)) \cdot \prod_{k = 1}^{b} (ap + k).$$

Note that $f'(1) = (2 - 1) \cdots ((p - 1) - 1) = (p - 2)!$, whereas $f(1) = (p - 1)!$.

It looks like you know how to compute each term quickly enough. There are a total of $a + b < 2p$ terms above. Does this work?

Comment: Thanks, yes source is Project Euler, Anyways generalised the question more to suit the answer. Can you share your Project Euler Friend's Key. Seems following you would be good for learning.

Comment: I still don't get it fully, I will try to explain with a small example which part I don't understand, Lets say N=140,p=7.so we will need product(1.2.3.4...140) modulo 49. for numbers 1-48 (excluding the 6 which are divisible by 7 and I understand we will  calculate these in recursive call and so we are skipping them for now),so among the rest 42, 40 of them pair up with their inverses and the remaining two product to form -1 , hence product for this group is -1. Similarly for the group 50-97. But what about 99-140, they would form an incomplete group. How would you compute product for 99-140 ?

Comment: @sibillalazzerini: you would have to end up doing some computation by explicitly multiplying it. Note that since $49 \times 3 = 147$, it might be better to compute the product until $146$ and then invert the extra elements (141 till 146). But I realise that this will again be expensive if $p^2$ is large.

Comment: yes exactly. thats $O(p^2)$ then you are essentially back to the same algo which is [standard for p](https://cp-algorithms.com/algebra/factorial-modulo.html#algorithm). You can at most multiple O(p) terms, that's what the entire challenge is about.

Comment: little optimization like doing for extra elements (141 till 146) isn't going to change the time complexity. what if my example was for $N=125$. Infact here the time complexity is worser than $O(P^{2})$ considering that you can't even precompute $P^{2}−1$ inverses. solving this in  $O(P^{2})$  is probably known for centuries. The papers you and others have linked must be doing it something better than  $O(P^{2})$ right?

Comment: I have updated the question with my additional findings on top of your answer .

Comment: @sibillalazzerini: I have updated my answer using the idea of the polynomial you considered. Note that the papers we linked need not necessarily be doing something better than $P^2$, because they need not be caring about the complexity of computations, but just the math. (Or they may not be worried about $p$ being big.)

Comment: Polynomial expansion by FFT Multiplication or Taylors Series expansion both introduces some degree of error. Will  have to let you know after testing out both.

Comment: @sibillalazzerini: The Taylor series that I've written has no error. There is an equality since we are working modulo $p^2$.

Comment: @sibillalazzerini: That was a typo, we have $1 \leqslant b < p$.